# Using SQLite how do I index columns in a CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: sqlite

How do I index a column in my CREATE TABLE statement? The table looks like

```
command.CommandText =
    "CREATE TABLE if not exists file_hash_list( " +
        "id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "hash  BLOB NOT NULL, " +
        "filesize INTEGER NOT NULL);";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want filesize to be index and would like it to be 4 bytes

Answer (score 138):

You can't do precisely what you're asking, but unlike some RDBMSs, SQLite is able to perform DDL inside of a transaction, with the appropriate result. This means that if you're really concerned about nothing ever seeing file_hash_list without an index, you can do

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE file_hash_list (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  hash BLOB NOT NULL,
  filesize INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX file_hash_list_filesize_idx ON file_hash_list (filesize);
COMMIT;
```

or the equivalent using the transaction primitives of whatever database library you've got there.

I'm not sure how *necessary* that really is though, compared to just doing the two commands outside of a transaction.

As others have pointed out, SQLite's indexes are all B-trees; you don't get to choose what the type is or what portion of the column is indexed; the entire indexed column(s) are in the index. It will still be efficient for range queries, it just might take up a little more disk space than you'd really like.

Comment: What could happen if two separate queries are used instead?

Comment: I mean, isn't everything committed at once usually? If not, when it IS the case, I guess that then it doesn't matter anymore, does it?

Comment: I'd just want to note that since version 3.8.0, there are partial indexes, which allows you to index only part of the column with a WHERE statement: http://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you can. Why can't you use a second query? And specifying the size of the index seems to be impossible in SQLite. But then again, it is SQ_Lite_ ;)

```
create index
    myIndex
on
    myTable (myColumn)
```